# How to display ContentChildren in ng-container?

Tags: angular, typescript

MWizardItemPage.html

```
<ng-template>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

I have an html page like this.

```
        <div *ngFor="let item of mobileWizardItemPages; let i = index">
            <mbsc-scrollview-item id= i >
                {{i}} --> this show the index !
                <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.templateRef"></ng-container> --> this did not show the content
            </mbsc-scrollview-item>
        </div>
```

Here it's how I got the content of itempage

```
@ContentChildren(MWizardItemPage) queryResult: QueryList<MWizardItemPage>;
this.mobileWizardItemPages = this.queryResult.toArray();
        this.mobileWizardItemPages[
            this.SelectedIndexWizardPage
        ].InnerPage.LoadAction();
```

I wanted to display mobileWizardItemPages' element in ngTemplateOutlet but I could not. How can I display mobileWizardItemPages' element in ngTemplateOutlet or in my html file ?